# arduino mini pro crashes when receiving bluetooth data

Tags: arduino

im using arduino mini pro 3.3v and the hc-06 to send and receive data between android app and arduino.
The problem is when i send data to the arduino it crashes (restarts). 
This project was working fine for some time. I have the HC-06 connected directly to the rx and tx as it is a 3.3v mini.
I have tried an other HC-06 and the same thing happens. Im guessing its the mini that is at fault. this isn't as easy to change as its soldered to a pcb circuit.

it sends data back to the app no problem and everything else seems ok.
Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the code with us?

Comment: It's usually stack-heap collision (aka stack overflow) or buffer overflow.